# Wrapping map visibility issues in sfml

Tags: c++, view, sfml

I'm implementing a wrapping map consisting of two parts and only the first view is visible and works as intended. 
The second view is invisible and I don't know why. If you go to the left, there is a a black area instead of the second view.
After having done many number changes/tests, it seems as the second view is limited to the area of the first view only.
With one tiled maps, that were not bigger than the screen size it worked like a charm, unlike here. Many thanks for any help in advance.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow mMainWindow(sf::VideoMode(1000,600), "Map", sf::Style::Close);
    sf::View view(sf::Vector2f(500, 300), sf::Vector2f(1000, 600)); 
    sf::View view2(sf::Vector2f(500, 300), sf::Vector2f(1000, 600));

    sf::Image mapimage;
    mapimage.loadFromFile("world1.jpg");  //1000*600 px
    sf::Texture maptexture;
    maptexture.loadFromImage(mapimage);
    sf::Sprite mapsprite(maptexture);
    sf::Sprite mapsprite2(maptexture);
    mapsprite.setPosition(0, 0);
    mapsprite2.setPosition(1000, 0);

    sf::RectangleShape viewrect;
    viewrect.setSize(sf::Vector2f(2000, 600));
    viewrect.setPosition(0, 0);
    viewrect.setFillColor(sf::Color(250,0,0,40));

    sf::RectangleShape viewrect2;
    viewrect2.setSize(sf::Vector2f(2000, 600));
    viewrect2.setPosition(0, 0);
    viewrect2.setFillColor(sf::Color(0,0,250,40));

    float fview2 = 1;
    view2.setViewport(sf::FloatRect(fview2, 0, 1, 1));
    int mapmovementvar = 0;

    while (mMainWindow.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;

        while (mMainWindow.pollEvent(event))
        {
            switch (event.type)
            {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                mMainWindow.close();
                break;
            }
        }
        if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left))
        {
            system("cls");
            view.move(-100, 0);
            fview2=fview2+0.1f;
            mapmovementvar--;

            if(mapmovementvar<0)
            {   
                mapmovementvar=19;
                fview2=-0.9f;
                view.reset(sf::FloatRect(1900, 0, 1000, 600));
                view2.reset(sf::FloatRect(-1000, 0, 1000, 600));
            }

            view2.setViewport(sf::FloatRect(fview2, 0, 1, 1));
            std::cout << "fview2 " << fview2 << std::endl;
            std::cout << "mapmovementvar " << mapmovementvar << std::endl;
        }

        mMainWindow.clear();

        mMainWindow.setView(view);
        mMainWindow.draw(mapsprite);
        mMainWindow.draw(mapsprite2);
        mMainWindow.draw(viewrect);

        mMainWindow.setView(view2);
        mMainWindow.draw(mapsprite);
        mMainWindow.draw(mapsprite2);
        mMainWindow.draw(viewrect2);

        mMainWindow.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have fixed the problem with the views you were having, but I think using views wasn't even needed in your case. See my code below which I think implement what you want.

## Initialization

As you can see, you can load Texture directly from a file if you don't absolutely need the Image object for other stuff. And views are overkill here and I think that's not the goal of views to be used like what you want.

```cpp
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    float screenWidth = 1000;

    sf::RenderWindow mMainWindow(sf::VideoMode(screenWidth, 600), "Map",
            sf::Style::Close);

    // no need to use image, you can load texture directly from a file
    sf::Texture maptexture;
    maptexture.loadFromFile("world1.jpg"); //1000*600 px

    // you only really need one sprite, but that's not really a problem.
    sf::Sprite mapsprite(maptexture);

    // you don't need views at all, just a position.
    sf::Vector2f pos;
```

## App loop

Nothing changed here.

```cpp
    while (mMainWindow.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;

        while (mMainWindow.pollEvent(event))
        {
            switch (event.type)
            {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                mMainWindow.close();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
```

## Keyboard input handling

When handling input, only change what's dependant on the input. Here, only the position changes. (And the sprite scale for zoom, but that's bonus stuff here)

```cpp
        // you may as well test with all directions because f*ck One Direction.
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left))
        {
            pos.x += 1.0f;
        }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right))
        {
            pos.x -= 1.0f;
        }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down))
        {
            pos.y -= 1.0f;
        }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up))
        {
            pos.y += 1.0f;
        }

        // bonus zoom
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Equal)) // + zoom
        {
            mapsprite.setScale(mapsprite.getScale().x + 0.001f,
                    mapsprite.getScale().y + 0.001f);
        }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Dash)) // - zoom
        {
            mapsprite.setScale(mapsprite.getScale().x - 0.001f,
                    mapsprite.getScale().y - 0.001f);
        }
```

## Adjusted position

Since we're always using the same map, we only need to keep track of the position inside one map rectangle. So, if we go pass that rectangle, we just adjust the position to get back inside the map and we do that before rendering so it's invisible that we just changed the map position.

```cpp
        // Here's all the magic happening, you loop your position around the width.
        float width = mapsprite.getGlobalBounds().width;
        if (pos.x <= -width)
        {
            pos.x += width;
        }
        else if (pos.x > 0)
        {
            pos.x -= width;
        }

        std::cout << "X pos : " << pos.x << std::endl;
```

## Rendering loop

We only need one Sprite object to achieve the rendering loop since we use the same Texture that the Sprite is referencing. We just give a new position to the Sprite, then draw it, then repeat. You can still use many Sprite objects without problem as Sprite is a light-weight object, but it would be useless here to use more than one.

```cpp
        mMainWindow.clear();

        for (int i = 0; pos.x + (i * width) < screenWidth; ++i)
        {

            // display each sprite with a new position according to the last one.
            mapsprite.setPosition(pos.x + (i * width), pos.y);
            mMainWindow.draw(mapsprite);

        }

        mMainWindow.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```